# CrankBrothers EggBeater 3 Rusted

Tags: maintenance, pedals

I've had a set of new EggBeater 3 pedals for 1 month and the left pedal is rusted. I don't understand why only one of the pedals is rusted and the other is not. Is this common and is there something in particular I should do about it?

Comment: Do you lay the bike down?

Comment: Just return it.